# Prevent Resharper Code Cleanup from breaking null conditional operator to new line

Tags: c#, resharper

When applying the Resharper code cleanup, the null conditional operator is wrapped to a new line:

After formatting

```
 var result = Get(s => s.Information == information)
                     ?.SingleOrDefault()
                     ?.Action;
```

Desired formatting:

```
 var result = Get(s => s.Information == information)?
                     .SingleOrDefault()?
                     .Action;
```

Which Resharper setting needs to be adjusted to achieve the desired formatting?

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately, that's not possible.